# creating implicit rules with multiple prerequisites in a makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile that has lots of similar looking statements:

```
ABC_01.exe: ABC_01.o ../constant.o
    gcc $^ -o $@ $(SOMEPATH)/bin/constant.dll

ABC_02.exe: ABC_02.o ../constant.o
    gcc $^ -o $@ $(SOMEPATH)/bin/constant.dll

ABC_03.exe: ABC_03.o ../constant.o
    gcc $^ -o $@ $(SOMEPATH)/bin/constant.dll

ABC_04.exe: ABC_04.o ../constant.o
    gcc $^ -o $@ $(SOMEPATH)/bin/constant.dll
```

I would like to know if I can create an implicit rule

```
%.exe:%.o ???
     gcc $^ -o $@ $(SOMEPATH)/bin/constant.dll
```

so that I don't have to repeat the rule for each executable target.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No problem:

```
ABC_%.exe: ABC_%.o ../constant.o
    gcc $^ -o $@ $(SOMEPATH)/bin/constant.dll
```